# Facing routing (RPDB) issue on Linux when using IP_HDRINCL option

Tags: linux, sockets, routes

I have been using the Linux (2.6.x) RPDB (Routing Policy DB) so as to implement source address based routing setting up dedicated routing tables for the desired sources as indicated below:

1. 0:      from all lookup local
2. 32765:  from source-IP-address lookup table-id
3. 32766:  from all lookup main
4. 32767:  from all lookup default

Further, my application uses raw socket to generate ICMP echo messages. The issue is that when 'IP_HDRINCL' socket option is set to '1' and the application builds up the entire IP header together with the source IP address then the corresponding routing table is not getting hit instead it hits the main routing table.

However, if I modify the application not to set IP_HDRINCL socket option and explicitly binds on the raw socket to specify the source address then it correctly hits the desired routing table.

Is it like one is required to bind on a socket to be able to make use of the source based routing capability of RPDB?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I know this is an old issue but do you remember if you found a solution/workaround?